# Replace part on string in list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, string-manipulation

I have a list with string and integers and want to replace one word in the string with an integer.

For Example if I have

```
 list={{1,"the dog jumped", "Tues : Wed},
       {2,"the fox ran", "Mon : Tues : Fri"},
       {3,"a dog jumped", "Wed : Mon : Tues"}}
```

I replace part of the string with integer values so `Mon->{1,0,0,0}` `Tues->{0,1,0,0}` `Wed->{0,0,1,0}` `Fri->{0,0,0,1}` `:->+`.

so I get

```
 list={{1, "the dog jumped", {0,1,0,0}+{0,0,1,0}},
       {2, "the fox ran", {1,0,0,0}+{0,1,0,0}+{0,0,0,1}},
       {3, "a dog jumped". {0,0,1,0}+{1,0,0,0}+{0,1,0,0}}
```

StringReplace gives me and error and ReplaceAll only works for the full string

Comment: Show the `StringReplace` and `ReplaceAll` expressions you have tried so far.

Comment: `ReplaceAll[list, {"Mon" -> {1, 0, 0, 0}, "Tues" -> {0, 1, 0, 0}}]`


`StringReplace[list, "Mon" -> {1, 0, 0, 0}]`

Comment: I noticed ReplaceAll only works for the whole string so StringReplace from Wolfram Documentation is what I wanted but doesn't seem to work for list. The error was `String or list of strings expected at position 1 in \
StringReplace[{{1,the dog jumped ,Tues : Wed : Sat },{2,the fox ran \
,Mon : Tues : Fri },{3,a dog jumped ,Wed : Mon : Tues }},Mon \
->{1,0,0,0}]. >>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you have a "." in your original expression, `"a dog jumped".` instead of `,` and also I do not know why `sat` is not there, so I made one up for it. But any way, is this what you wanted?

```
list = {{1, "the dog jumped", "Tues : Wed : Sat"}, {2, "the fox ran", 
    "Mon : Tues : Fri"}, {3, "a dog jumped", "Wed : Mon : Tues"}};
rep = {":" -> "+", "Mon" -> "{1,0,0,0}" , "Tues" -> "{0,1,0,0}" , 
   "Wed" -> "{0,0,1,0}" , "Fri" -> "{0,0,0,1}", "Sat" -> "{0,0,1,1}"};
list[[All, 3]] = StringReplace[#[[3]], rep] & /@ list;
list
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to add these `{0,0,1,1}+....` etc... this can also be done by converting them to Expressions.

edit:

If you want to add these `{0,0,1,1}+....` you can use `ToExpression` as follows

```
list = {{1, "the dog jumped", "Tues : Wed : Sat"}, {2, "the fox ran", 
    "Mon : Tues : Fri"}, {3, "a dog jumped", "Wed : Mon : Tues"}};
rep = {":" -> "+", "Mon" -> "{1,0,0,0}" , "Tues" -> "{0,1,0,0}" , 
   "Wed" -> "{0,0,1,0}" , "Fri" -> "{0,0,0,1}", "Sat" -> "{0,0,1,1}"};
list[[All, 3]] = ToExpression[StringReplace[#[[3]], rep] & /@ list];
list
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The . was an error. Fixed typos thanks. This is a toy model for a bigger data set that I have. So The solution seems to be with StringReplace so it look like you have to specify what column to replace. Correct?

Comment: @MTR Well, yes, you have to tell it which part to replace ofcourse. You have a list of lists. And you want to only apply the replace on part of each list.

Comment: OK cool thanks so lets just say my second column also had days of the week and wanted to replace in all columns would I have to `list[[All, 2;;3]] = StringReplace[#[[2;;3]], rep] & /@ list;` My notation might be wrong to to say column 2-3. but is that the right idea

Comment: Also yes my goal is to add them together